# loop on page makes shortcode fail

Tags: shortcode, loop

I have this typical *WordPress* page (page.php):

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<div id="rightcol">
 <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

All works fine; have some shortcode, *[gallery]*, in the page content.

So then I add a simple loop to the page to display random posts form a given category:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=interesting_sites&posts_per_page=3&orderby=rand'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Then, shortcode in page content fails! Why this happens? Any ideas?

Comment: What version of WP are you using?

Comment: It be 3.2 - Related to the version (haven't tested)?

Comment: are you using a page template? are you trying to show the gallery before the list of posts?  you might need to use two loops to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use `query_posts()` for anything other than the main loop of that page and use either `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`, try this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category_name' => 'interesting_sites',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    )
);
while ($my_query->have_posts()){
    $my_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: _Awesome_ that - I will learn the differences. Sláinte.